# How to pass `this` object to function through anchor link and convert it to jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm having trouble with something that I'm trying to simplify. When a link is clicked, I want its CSS to be updated via jQuery. My main question is, how can I take Javascript's `this` object and convert it to a jQuery object for easier handling?

Here is what my code looks like:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a href="javascript:load('page.php', this);">load some page</a>
<a href="javascript:load('other.php', this);">load other page</a>

// JS
function load(url, linkObj) {
    loadPageWithURL(url);
    $(linkObj).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
}
```

However, this does not work. Obviously I'm doing more than an underline when a link is selected, but you get the idea. Am I using `this` wrong or is it just a matter of converting the raw JS object to an object recognized by jQuery?

Comment: If you are using jQuery you should keep the unobtrusive principle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use inline events!  Use jQuery to bind them.

```
<a class="load" href="page.php">load some page</a>
<a class="load" href="other.php">load other page</a>
```

Then in JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    $('.load').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        loadPageWithURL(this.href);
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    });
});
```

UPDATE: If new links are being added after the page is loaded, you need to use:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.load', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        loadPageWithURL(this.href);
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this solution better because it's cleaner and more portable. Thank you!

Comment: The links are being loaded with ajax as well, I forgot to mention that. I tried appending your JS code to the top of my JS source file and changing the class to `load` as well but it doesn't prevent the link from executing and still takes me to `domain.com/whatever` instead of executing `javascript:load(whatever);`. Would I need to call this function each time the links are loaded or would that be inefficient?

Comment: @danL: Are new links being added after the page is loaded?

Comment: Thank you for that very prompt response, the new code works great!To answer your question, yes, new links are being added after the page is loaded.  I'm still trying to learn about jQuery efficiency and this has really helped me a lot, thanks again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33596/discussion-between-danl-and-rocket-hazmat)

Answer (score 7):

That function would work fine (`$(linkObj)` is correct), but you have your script in the `href` instead of on `onclick` attribute. So it won't ever execute.

Change:

```
<a href="load('page.php', this);">load some page</a>
<a href="load('other.php', this);">load other page</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="#" onclick="load('page.php', this); return false;">load some page</a>
<a href="#" onclick="load('other.php', this); return false;">load other page</a>
```

Comment: Oh, okay. I wasn't aware that the `this` object could only be passed through a specific JS event handler. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't have to be a 'specific' event handler, it only has to *be* an event-handler; albeit the `javascript` protocol can sometimes serve the same, or a similar, effect (albeit it's a horrible practice).

Comment: I would suggest *not* using `onclick` attributes.

Comment: @danL `this` can be passed into any Javascript function, it's just that you have to actually do that. An href attribute doesn't expect Javascript, it expects a URI.

Answer (score 4):

One of the advantages of using jQuery is that you can easily write *[unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)*, it mean that you don't need to mix HTML with JavaScript. You can improve and achieve you requirements by refactoring your code as follows.

The HTML:

```
<a href="page.php">load some page</a>
<a href="other.php">load other page</a>
```

And your JavaScript code in one place:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    load($link.attr('href'), $link);
    return false;
  });
});
```

**Note**: The previous code will *catch all links*, if you want don't want to do this, you can add particular class name. Suppose the class name is `load` then the code should be rewritten as follows:

The HTML:

```
<a class="load" href="page.php">load some page</a>
<a class="load" href="other.php">load other page</a>
```

And your JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.load', function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    load($link.attr('href'), $link);
    return false;
  });
});
```

If you have any particular related to the code provided, put it on the comments.